# Updating image in Chat bubble using Chatto library ios

Tags: ios, swift, chat

I have existing Model where I am adding Chatto for UI so I am able to create a message with placeholder but unable to figure out the best way to change the same after download.

Library Link
https://github.com/badoo/Chatto

i am using chatto test app with DemoPhotoMessageModel.
then i use the follwing to add

```
var imgMess = DemoPhotoMessageModel(messageModel: messageModel, imageSize: placeholder.size, image: placeholder)
self.slidingWindow.insertItem(imgMess, position: .bottom)
self.delegate?.chatDataSourceDidUpdate(self)


ImageDownloader.default.downloadImage(with: downloadURL, options: [], progressBlock: nil) {[unowned self]
                            (image, error, url, data) in
                            print("Downloaded Image: \(image)")

                            if let img = image, let imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img){
imgMess.setImage(img: img) //I updated the default implementation changing the image from var to let constant


}
}
```

Wha I have also tried is updating the object in slidingWindow itself. That also doesn't work. What will be the possible solution to create a new object with new uid or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can download image in `willBeShown()` method of view model. As you need to pass url to view model, you need to subclass couple of classes. Please see the full solution in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/rinat-enikeev/3bd73ab1ac0b0f0591de72781bba165e). Please feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: This almost solved my very same issue.  However, I note that you need the correct image size (pixel dimensions) ahead of time when you create your ImageModel:

let chatItem = ImageMessageModel(messageModel: model,
                                     imageSize: size,
                                     placeholder: UIImage(named: "placeholder")!,
                                     url: <your url>)
At this point in time,  I don't know the dimensions of the image that is to be downloaded, just its URL.  But if I use the placeholder size, it won't resize when real image is downloaded.

Comment: The base class PhotoMessageViewModel in ChattoAdditions apparently makes the image Observable, just for the very purpose of being able to update it later as you do in this code... but imageSize seems to be only settable once on initialization and it comes from the photoMessage.imageSize?   So am I right in surmising that I need to change my code so my app is able to know what the image size on the other end is, before it downloads it?